# Where to implement the custom button logic?

Tags: magento2, custom-button

I created a button via following code:

```
<?php

namespace UV\Bestellung\Plugin;

class Buttons
{
public function beforePushButtons(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
) {

    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
        $buttonList->add(
            'bestellschein',
            ['label' => __('Bestellschein'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(window.location.href)', 'class' => 'reset'],
            -1
        );
    }
}
}

?>
```

It appears and it is clickable but obviously it has no logic and is doing nothing.
How can I give it a logic and implement it?

Thanks!:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create controller and implement the logic there (check `$url`). When you click on the button, you will reach to your controller and there you can implement your logic.

```
namespace UV\Bestellung\Plugin;

class Buttons
{
    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {

        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
            $url = $subject->getUrl('custom_module/order/custom/id/'.$SOMEID);
            $buttonList->add(
                'bestellschein',
                ['label' => __('Bestellschein'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'{$url}\')', 'class' => 'reset'],
                -1
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routers.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="custom_module" id="custom_module">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Custom.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

class Custom  extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{


    public function execute()
    {
        // your logic here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok it doesn't work yet. My Custom.php is located here now: UV/Bestellung/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Custom.php. "        $url = $subject->getUrl('UV/Bestellung/Controller/Order/Custom');" doesn't work.

Comment: Did you create routers.xml file?  you have to create controller and url properly.

Comment: yes I created it. That is it: '<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="UV_Bestellung" id="UV_Bestellung">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>'

Comment: if you created router.xml why is the $url is still : $url = $subject->getUrl('UV/Bestellung/Controller/Order/Custom'); ? The url should be: $subject->getUrl('UV_Bestellung/order/custom'); (all lower case) check first how to controller magento controller and URL

Comment: see in my answer what I have done. I dont know why it is not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have done that now:

> UV/Bestellung/Plugin/Buttons.php

```
<?php

namespace UV\Bestellung\Plugin;

class Buttons
{
public function beforePushButtons(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
) {

    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
        $url = $subject->getUrl('UV_Bestellung/order/custom');
        $buttonList->add(
            'bestellschein',
            ['label' => __('Bestellschein'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'{$url}\')', 'class' => 'reset'],
            -1
        );
    }
}
}

?>
```

> UV/Bestellung/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<config>
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="bestellschein" frontName="Bestellschein">
            <module name="UV_Bestellung" before="UV_Bestellung"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> UV/Bestellung/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Custom.php

```
<?php
namespace UV\Bestellung\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;
class Custom extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // your logic here 
    }
}
?>
```

When I call the page where the button is located, it is just blank.
Error logs says that this line is the problem:

```
$url = $subject->getUrl('UV_Bestellung/order/custom');
```

Comment: $url = $subject->getUrl('UV_Bestellung/order/custom');
Should be $url = $subject->getUrl('Bestellschein/order/custom'); 

In routers.xml, the frontName='...'  is the URL of magento magento 
please check URL => http://MAGENTO_URL/ADMINPATH/bestellschein/order/custom is accessible?

Comment: 404 Site not found. What do you mean by frontName="..." is the URL of Magento?

Comment: check routers.xml  <route id="bestellschein" frontName="Bestellschein">  frontName should be the part of URL. in your example: Bestellschein not UV_Bestellung